# Why did Devaki keep having children even though she knew they'd all be killed except for the last one?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, vishnu-purana, children, mother

Why did Devaki keep having children even though she knew they'd all be killed except for the last one?

It must have been hard for a mom to see her newborn baby being killed- but she still continued to have more kids.

Answer (score 4):

1. ### Who were the 6 infants that were killed by *Kaṁsa* ?

According to the *Devībhāgavatapurāṇa* & *Harivaṁśa*, these 6 infants were known as the *Ṣaṛagarbha*. They were initially born as the mind-born sons of *ṛṣi Marīci*, but were cursed by *Prajāpati Brahmā* to be born as *asura*s after they mocked Him for harboring carnal desires towards His own daughter *Sandhyā* under the influence of *Kāma*. So, they were born as sons of *Kālanemi*. In that birth, they propitiated *Brahmā* & from Him, obtained the boon of being invincible to *deva*s, *asura*s, humans, *ṛṣi*s, *nāgā*s, *gandharva*s, *yakṣa*s, beasts & weapons. *Hiranyākṣaśipu*, who had also obtained a same boon of sorts, became insecure on learning about this. He feared that the *Ṣaṛagarbha* might turn against him after this, so he cursed them to be killed immediately after birth on their next birth by he who was their father at that birth i.e *Kālanemi* & for his own security, consigned them to deep sleep. On the command of *Bhagavāna Viṣṇu*, *Devī Yoganidrā* extracted the souls of the *Ṣaṛagarbha* from *Pātāla* & placed them into the womb of *Devakī*. And as per the curse of *Hiranyākṣaśipu*, they were killed immediately after birth by *Kaṁsa*, who was actually the reincarnation of *Kālanemi*.

2. ### Why *Devakī* had to suffer such an ordeal ?

After the deaths of her only 2 sons *Hiranyākṣa* & *Hiranyākṣaśipu*, *Diti* was understandably griefstruck. At this time, according to the *Matsyapurāṇa*, on the advice of *ṛṣi Vaśiṣṭha*, *Diti* propitiated *Bhagavāna Viṣṇu* through the observance of *Madanadvādaśī vrata* with the aim to obtain a son who would subdue *Indra*. When *Diti* became pregnant again after completing the *vrata*, *Indra* became insecure. So, on one occasion when *Diti* fell asleep without washing her feet, *Indra* entered inside *Diti*'s body through her nostrils & when he failed to destroy the foetus, he cut it into 7 pieces. On being cut, the foetus created a loud howling noise. *Indra* said '*Mā ruda*' (i.e Don't cry) & silenced them by cutting each piece into 7 pieces, making a total of 49 pieces. *Diti*'s husband, the *ṛṣi Kaśyapa* converted these 49 pieces into the 49 *Marut*s (named after the appellation given by *Indra*), the stormy winds who accompany *Indra* & are controlled by *Rudra*. According to the *Devībhāgavatapurāṇa*, it was actually *Indra*'s mother *Aditi*, insecure & jealous of her co-wife's unborn child, who directed *Indra* to attempt aborting the foetus inside *Diti*'s womb. So *Diti* cursed *Aditi* to bear the grief of losing her own 7 newborn children. That curse was fulfilled when *Aditi* reincarnated as *Devakī* & bore the deaths of her 6 newborn babies shortly after their births & the supposed abortion of her 7th child.

So we have

- a mother destined to bear the pain of losing 7 of her own newborn children
- 6 persons destined to be killed immediately after birth
- A person destined to kill 6 newborn babies.

Now the question arises

3. ### Was it avoidable ?

By now, it is clear that all this was pre-destined. All sources state that *Kaṁsa* was initially planning to kill *Devakī* but *Vasudeva* managed to save *Devakī*'s life in exchange of her children. According to the *Devībhāgavatapurāṇa*, when *Vasudeva* voluntarily came forward to surrender their 1st child, *Kaṁsa* did actually spared that infant, stating that he sought only the 8th child. But *ṛṣi Nārada* put forward a chicanerous argument - the term 8th child didn't necessarily meant that it must be the 8th one in order of birth, it could be anyone among *Devakī*'s children in any order (merit, physical strength, height etc). He also fed *Kaṁsa*'s insecurity by stating that monarchs well-versed in the art of politics & statecraft shouldn't spare even the weakest of their enemies, because that spared enemy might grow so strong in future that he can't be subdued like before (take for example the Taliban in our times). The fact that *Kaṁsa* acted upon such an illogical argument indicate his own cruel disposition.

A counter-argument is - *Vasudeva* could have just not impregnated *Devaki* again after the death of their 1st/7th child.
Our answer - The term '*Devaki*'s 8th child' didn't necessarily meant that all of them must be sired by *Devakī*'s legitimate husband. Since the prophecy referred to Devaki's 8th child, it was clear that nothing could prevent *Devaki* from conceiving atleast 8 times. So it's better to have all the 8 children fathered by *Devakī*'s legitimate husband than to allow somebody else do it. When carnal desire hits hard, it is practically impossible for ordinary people to resist its pangs. *Pāṇdu* indulged in sex with *Mādrī* inspite of being well-aware of the curse placed upon him. When people who can't even afford the basic salt to season their parboiled rice (as they say in Bengali - নুন আনতে পান্তা ফুরোয়) will not leave the chance of begetting children, then what to say of others.

So in short - whatever happened was due to destiny.